# How to measure the similarity of two contours - extracted from images using python?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, contour, similarity

I am doing a project related to comparing the similarity of 2 images with shapes (the number of shapes in the images are different), I have drawn contours for 2 images but I can't find any perfect method to measure the similarity between the two contours? (And the shapes in the images are different size.) I am a newbie, can anyone help me? Thank you so much!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBAJP.jpg)

Comment: See two different shape comparison methods at https://learnopencv.com/shape-matching-using-hu-moments-c-python/.

Comment: You can try [matchShapes](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaadc90cb16e2362c9bd6e7363e6e4c317). It uses Hu moments. There's an example [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d45/tutorial_py_contours_more_functions.html).

Comment: Thank you so much but the number of shape in the images are different so I can not use matchShapes

Comment: show your input data, untouched

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have added the image in the description above.

Comment: "contour matching" is a term that yields good search results.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the IOU measure. (Its very easy and quite good, although it doesn't strictly look at the contour).

````
     (a & b).area
IOU= ----------
     (a | b).area```
````